# Appending a python dictionary to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to export some API JSON data to a csv, but I only want some bits of it. I've tried `row.append`, but I'm getting the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

I'm new to python, and a bit confused as to why it wants an integer.

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv

outfile_path='/NYTComments.csv'

writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path, 'w'))

url = urllib2.Request('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/community/v2/comments/recent?api-key=ea7aac6c5d0723d7f1e06c8035d27305:5:66594855')

parsed_json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

print parsed_json

for comment in parsed_json['results']:
    row = []
    row.append(str(comment['commentSequence'].encode('utf-8')))
    row.append(str(comment['commentBody'].encode('utf-8')))
    row.append(str(comment['commentTitle'].encode('utf-8')))
    row.append(str(comment['approveDate'].encode('utf-8')))
    writer.writerow(row)
```

The parsed_json printed looks like this:

```
{u'status': u'OK',
u'results':
    {u'totalCommentsReturned': 25,
    u'comments':
        [{
            u'status': u'approved',
            u'sharing': 0,
            u'approveDate': u'1349378866',
            u'display_name': u'Seymour B Moore',
            u'userTitle': None,
            u'userURL': None,
            u'replies': [],
            u'parentID': None,
            u'articleURL': u'http://fifthdown.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/10/03/thursday-matchup-cardinals-vs-rams/',
            u'location': u'SoCal',
            u'userComments': u'api.nytimes.com/svc/community/v2/comments/user/id/26434659.xml',
            u'commentSequence': 2,
            u'editorsSelection': 0,
            u'times_people': 1,
            u'email_status': u'0',
            u'commentBody': u"I know most people won't think this is a must watch game, but it will go a long way .... (truncated)",
            u'recommendationCount': 0,
            u'commentTitle': u'n/a'
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is comment a dictionary? It sounds like it might be a string.

Comment: the dictionary is parsed_json

Comment: Yes, but it appears you are treating comment as a dictionary, if it isn't a dictionary, then you have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for comment in parsed_json['results']: #'comment' contains keys, not values
```

should be

```
for comment in parsed_json['results']['comments']:
```

`parsed_json['results']` itself is another dictionary.

`parsed_json['results']['comments']` is the list of dictionaries you want to iterate.

Comment: This also yields this error:
row.append(str(comment['commentSequence'].encode('utf-8')))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Can you please add the output of `print parsed_json` to your question, even if a sample and not the full output?

Comment: Thank you. I just did. Above you can see an example of one comment.

Comment: Thanks for adding the output, although I had been able to figure it from using your code and the url inside it :) Should work now!

Comment: You are my hero. can I donate a beer/coffee to you?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the gesture! But all I ask and hope is that you don't just use the code above, but understand and learn from it (and from Dougal's excellent answer).

Comment: I believe I did. First, I was trying to retrieve keys, not elements as I wanted. Then, I didn't realize the JSON had two levels to it, results then comments. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're making a mistake that I make all the time. Instead of

```
for comment in parsed_json['results']:
```

you want

```
for comment_name, comment in parsed_json['results'].iteritems():
```

(or `.items()` if you're using Python 3).

Just iterating over a dictionary (like `parsed_json['results']` presumably is) gives you the *keys* of the dictionary, not the elements. If you do

```
for thing in {'a': 1, 'b': 2}:
```

then `thing` will loop over 'a' and 'b'.

Then, because that key is apparently a string, you're trying to do something like `"some_name"['commentSequence']`, which is causing the error message you're seeing.

`dict.iteritems()`, on the other hand, gives you an iterator that'll give you elements like `('a', 1)` and then `('b', 2)`; the two variables in the `for` loop then get assigned to the two elements there, so `comment_name == 'a'` and `comment == 1` here.

Since it seems like you're not actually using the key from `parsed_json['results']`, you could also loop `for comment in parsed_json['results'].itervalues()` instead.

Comment: You're right, I want the elements not the keys. When I change that out, I'm getting:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable